# Redirect on IIS after Azure B2C Login Failure

Tags: azure, iis, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up Azure AD B2C to do authentication for a product I am using. I have raised a ticket with the vendor as to why the product is not handling the Azure B2C failures but need to have a workaround in.

Can I use IIS to capture generic errors and redirect for example if I get this error where the user has exceeded the maximum number for retries for multi-factor authentication. Currently I get a error 500 screen

Message contains error: 'server_error', error_description: 'AADB2C90151: User has exceeded the maximum number for retries for multi-factor authentication.
Correlation ID: aaeebc1b-2a5e-4686-97e4-13d4184a5889

Can I use IIS to capture generic errors and redirect for example if I get this error where the user has exceeded the maximum number for retries for multi-factor authentication. Currently I get a error 500 screen as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To configure IIS to catch generic errors and redirect, you can follow these steps:

1. Open IIS Manager and select your website
2. Open the "Error Pages" module.
3. Double-click the 500 status code option and in the "Response Action" section, do one of the following:

- Select Insert content from static file into the error response to serve static content, for example, an .html file, for the custom error.
- Select Execute a URL on this site to serve dynamic content, for example, an .asp file for the custom error.
- Select Respond with a 302 redirect to redirect client browsers to a different URL that contains the custom error file.

In the File path text box, type the path of the custom error page if you chose Insert content from static file into the error response or the URL of the custom error page if you use either the Execute a URL on this site or Respond with a 302 redirect, and then click OK.

Reference link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis#custom-error-options

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

[How to catch HTTP Error 400 - Bad Requests and redirect them properly on either asp.net application or in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066031/how-to-catch-http-error-400-bad-requests-and-redirect-them-properly-on-either)